# How to rotate an object in certain range in OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have built a hammer, and I want to rotate the hammer quickly to strike a blow when I press a specific keyboard.

I have used a timer function to achieve this. Right now my hammer can rotate 360 degrees when I press a specific keyboard, my goal is to rotate the hammer between 90 and -90 degrees.

My code:

```
bool stopRotation = false;
void weaponController(int val) 
{
    if (stopRotation != false) {
           zr++;   //the default angle is 0
           glutPostRedisplay();
           glutTimerFunc(1, weaponController, 1);
    } 
}
void specialkey(unsigned char key, int x, int y) 
{ 
    case 't':
    stopRotation = true;
    glutTimerFunc(10,weaponController,0);
    break;
    
    case 'T':
    stopRotation = false;
    break;
}
```

How can I do that? Thanks for any helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `zr` is the rotation of your hammer then I see it like this:

```cpp
int zr=0,dzr=+1; // might be a float I do not know as you did not share
bool stopRotation = false;
void weaponController(int val) 
{
    if (stopRotation != false) {
           zr+=dzr;   //the default angle is 0
           if (zr>+90){ dzr=-1; zr=+90+dzr; }
           if (zr<-90){ dzr=+1; zr=-90+dzr; }          
           glutPostRedisplay();
           glutTimerFunc(1, weaponController, 1);
    } else { zr=0; dzr=+1; }
}
```

so simply `dzr` is the direction of the rotation that is reversed on each crossing of the +/-90 deg barriers. When hammer is not used then its position and direction is reseted to start conditions....

Comment: It works! Thank you for helping :). So basically, when the angle is big than 90 degrees, the dzr will be negative, and when the angle is smaller than -90 degree it will be positive right?

Comment: @AllenLi yes ... the `dzr` is angular speed of the hammer ... you can even modulate it with function (like `sin()`  or linearly interpolate or whatever so on one side the speed is zero and on the hit side the speed is max while hammering down ... then when releasing hammer from target the speed is zero again tops at mid position and get to zero away from target and then cycle again ,,,) to achieve even more realistic effect ....